# Play .swf as standalone launch icon in windows8

Tags: windows-8, flash

Here's what we have:

1. A lonely 65 year old lady after two strokes. Her reactions are very slow. The lady wants to play extremely simple flash games, but she has no internet. She knows nothing about computing . The only thing she learned to perform on the PC: Click on the huge W8 icons, click on X to close the application, press Windows button and open the application again. She plays with arrows. There is no any way she will learn "launch player/chrome/->open/open with etc" actions or any other pc skills. There is no one near her who can help with the PC.
2. Windows8 powered Asus.
3. swf game files.

The task:

Create a standalone application *for every* swf file in a way that the final result is just icons of windows8 launch screen: I mean separate clickable icons for every swf-based application.

Please explain how can I perform this task. PLEASE, note I do not need any Player recommendations if the user should open the player and look for the files or launch swf files not from Windows8 launch window - i.e. there is no any way to launch apps from desktop.

Any detailed answers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to play SWF files without browser](http://superuser.com/questions/106258/how-to-play-swf-files-without-browser)

Comment: @DoktoroReichard no, it is not duplicate! I need the way to launch the swf as an ICON ON W8 START SCREEN

Comment: You can either download Adobe Projector (mentioned on the question I linked, which enables you to run .swf files without a browser) or you can associate .swf files with whatever browser you have. At any rate, this should make opening any .swf file, even those on the desktop, as easy as clicking on them.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard as I wrote, I need a launch NOT from desktop, but from launch window... if it is possible, that will be cool

Comment: @DoktoroReichard Please, understand - i am OSX user, so I don't really know how to perform all the W8 porting

Comment: I apologize then. From what I've read, it seems you want to place some shortcuts on the Metro menu (i.e. the one with the big square buttons). A preliminary search lead me to [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/start-screen-tutorial) Microsoft post, which deals on how to pin applications on the Start Screen. I also don't use Windows 8, but this seems like a starting point.